# How to style my HTML form using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a basic HTML form that uses an image background:

```html
<form style="
    background:url(http://moneythink.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Moneythink-Newsletter-Signup-Background.jpg) no-repeat; 
    padding:90px 0px 60px 122px;">
    <input type="email" value="Email" name="EMAIL" 
        class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" 
        style="width: 100px;" style="padding-bottom: 5px;"> 
    <input type="image" src="http://moneythink.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Submit-Button.jpg" 
        alt="Submit button" style=" padding-left: 57px; padding-bottom: -40px;" 
        name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe">
</form>
```

All is looking as expected, except, for some reason, I can't get the Submit button to appear directly underneath the text field; it keeps appearing next to it, on the right.

Any tips on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the CSS, apply `display: block` to the submit button, or - if using floats for layout - `clear: both`.

This will render the button as a block level element in the flow, resulting in the desired layout.

#### Reference

- [Block-level elements on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Comment: Awesome, using display: block fixed it. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

[Use a stylesheet](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/applyingcss/). Inline CSS will make your eyes bleed.

After you do this, making the buttons block-level elements *might* do the trick (depending on your desired layout):

```
form input[type="image"] {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<style>
--your style--  
</style>

<body>
<form>
 --your class-- 
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

like this(for shadow text php):

```
<?php

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";

echo "<style>";

echo '.inner_text_shadow{text-shadow: 1px 1px white, -1px -1px #444;}';
echo '.default{font-size:30px;color: darkred;font-weight:bold;}';
echo '</style>';
echo '<body>   <p class="inner_text_shadow default">FreeClup Best Code</p></body>';
echo "</html>";
?>
```